# How to enable Visual Style of the Form in Visual Studio Designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using Visual Studio 2019. Appearance of Form in Designer looks older than in running application.

Is it intended to be so, and is it possible to change the look in the Designer?

[image]

Comment: try changing your theme first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2019

Comment: Tried but does not make difference.

Comment: The form which is hosted in designer is not a top-level form and the top-level window theme will not apply on it. (It may be a bug in windows API or it may be by design, but it doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio, Windows Forms .NET or your theme settings.)

Comment: For this, you can suggest a feature on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=61).

Comment: @KyleWang As far as I know, it's a Windows feature, not a VS feature. For example even if you use [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set a notepad window as child of another notepad window you see similar behavior in rendering the titlebar. Here in this example, VS has nothing to do with rendering notepad titlebar, it's solely OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it. It's a Windows feature(bug), not a VS or .NET feature(bug).

The form which is hosted in designer is not a top-level form and as a result the top-level Window theme will not apply on it. It may be a bug in Windows or it may be by design, but it doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio, Windows Forms .NET or your theme settings.

For example even if you use [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set a notepad window as child of another notepad window you see similar behavior in rendering the titlebar. Here in this example, VS has nothing to do with rendering notepad titlebar, it's solely OS:

[image]

Above example has been created by the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parent = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    parent.WaitForInputIdle();

    var edit = FindWindowEx(parent.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
    SetWindowPos(edit, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0080);

    var child = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    child.WaitForInputIdle();
    SetParent(child.MainWindowHandle, parent.MainWindowHandle);

    SetWindowPos(child.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 30, 30, 300, 200, 0x0000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use Ui components such as GunaUI or DevComponent. then your Form will look better.
I don't know if you meant this by saying"Appearance of Form in Designer looks older than in running application"
but it's better to use components.